# Split Long Filename string in two Lines with Adobe Javascript

Tags: javascript, filenames, adobe

I am newbie using Javascript in Adobe. I have written script that catch the file name and add it as a title in the document, but problem is it doesn't split in 2 lines long file names. So long text file names are out of the page border.

For example file name is 
"This is a text that I need to split in two lines How to write the script in order to split the long text and fit in the page"

This is just a sample. What I need to edit? And is it possible?

```
var trFileName = this.documentFileName.replace(/.*\/|\.pdf$/ig,""); //remove .pdf extension
var pageAmount = this.numPages; //define how many pages are there

this.addWatermarkFromText({
cText: trFileName,
nStart: 0,
nEnd: pageAmount,
nFontSize: 18,
aColor: color.blue,
cFont: "Helvetica-Bold",
nTextAlign: app.constants.align.center,
nHorizAlign: app.constants.align.center,
nVertAlign: app.constants.align.top,
//nHorizValue: -25, 
nVertValue: -87.87
})
```

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: No, it not. Programming questions are off-topic. Please **read the javascript tag** as you were already told to "**Programming questions are off topic here; ask on Stack Overflow instead.**"

Comment: Comments are not the place top discuss this. If you disagree you may ask a question on [meta].

Comment: I already voted to migrate. You can also flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it (be specific about where you want it moved to).

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the documentation for Acrobat the quick way to do this is to add and use the `bPercentage: -1` property which ought to scale the watermark to fit the page with a max of 100%. Obviously, the longer the text, the smaller the the typesize, but it ought to only scale when needed.

The big problem here is "how big is too big?" Since most fonts are not fixed-width. So if you do not have some function to check the size of the type in that font, you would need to set up a temp image, set the type, then measure the dimensions of the image, then decide how much to break the text.

The worst case for English though is probably going to be an endless string of `W`, so if you want to hard code the font size and some reasonable character limit, you can get a reasonable max character count by counting how many Ws it takes to go out of bounds.

Once you have that number you can split the string.

One way to split a string is to use substring:

```
    var cDisplayText = trFilename;

var nMaxChars = 10;
var cAdobeNewline = '\r';
var cLineBreakChar = '-';

if (cDisplayText.length > nMaxChars && cDisplayText.length > 0) {
  cDisplayText = cDisplayText.substring(0, nMaxChars) 
  + cLineBreakChar 
  + cAdobeNewline 
  +  cDisplayText.substring(nMaxChars);
}
```

And then replace `cText: trFileName,` with `cText: cDisplayText,`

I have not tested this and my javascript has atrophied a little, but the idea is to test the string length and insert a hyphen and a line break.

This (obviously) does not account for case where there is more than 1 line break required.

Comment: It doesn't work. But if it would work I would prefer max word string instead of max chars. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: If your file name is "geological_survey_Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.pdf", a word count will not work. something to consider

Comment: I have preformed file names and there is no any specific symbols or characters. There are only space characters and words. So words count option is the best solution for me.